# After applying jquery datatable and bootstrap on gridview, why it columns are far apart?

Tags: jquery, html, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I have used bootstrap and jquery datatable on gridivew. It works but the columns are very large and apart from each other which doesn't look good. I want to make it  a bit small and near to each other but couldn't.

Gridview Code:

```
<div class="table-responsive table-sm DIV">
  <asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployees" runat="server" CssClass="table table-borderless table-striped">
     <Columns>
       <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/assets/img/icons/view.png" ShowSelectButton="true" SelectText="View" />
       <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ShowEditButton="true" EditImageUrl="~/assets/img/icons/pencil.png" />
       <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" DeleteImageUrl="~/assets/img/icons/trashbin.png" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Code

```
  Protected Sub dgvEmployees_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles dgvEmployees.RowCommand
        If e.CommandName = "Select" Then
            Dim RowIndex As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)
            Dim EmpID As String = dgvEmployees.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(3).Text
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("EmployeeDetails.aspx?EId={0}&Action={1}", Server.UrlEncode(EmpID), Server.UrlEncode("View")))
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "Edit" Then
            Dim RowIndex As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)
            Dim EmpID As String = dgvEmployees.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(3).Text
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("EmployeeDetails.aspx?EId={0}&Action={1}", Server.UrlEncode(EmpID), Server.UrlEncode("Edit")))
        ElseIf e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
            'Dim RowIndex As Int16 = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument)
            'Dim EmpID As String = dgvEmployees.Rows(RowIndex).Cells(3).Text
            'Dim EmployeeBLL = New EmployeeBLL()
            'EmployeeBLL.DeleteEmployeeID(Convert.ToInt16(EmpID))
            'GetAllEmployees()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Script:

```
   <script src="assets/js/core/jquery.3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugin/datatables/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


                  $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvEmployees').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
                      "responsive": true,
                      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                  });

        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_dgvEmployees').DataTable();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vb.net

Use the DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode see the available options and choose one that fits for you, hope it helps

There is an option there to grow columns automatically to fit the data

For asp.net

Set ItemStyle width to fixed width for others columns. And set GridView width to 100%

Hope it helps